# Problem sending port-directed Data SMS on HTC EVO 4G

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to send and receive port-directed SMS from an HTC EVO 4G to itself using `SmsManager.sendDataMessage()` and the device is giving a NullPointerException quite deep in the OS.

Here is the code that kicks off the exception:

```
manager.sendDataMessage(phonenumber, null, (short) 8091, data,piSend, piDelivered);
```

I think I have the appropriate permissions declared in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Here's the stack trace I'm getting:

```
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sen dData(ISms.java:682)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendDataMessage(SmsMa nager.java:546)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at com.varma.samples.smsdemo.MainActivity.sendSms(Mai nActivity.java:66)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at com.varma.samples.smsdemo.MainActivity.access$0(Ma inActivity.java:50)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at com.varma.samples.smsdemo.MainActivity$1.onClick(M ainActivity.java:98)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587 )
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92 )
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.jav a:4263)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCa ller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit .java:597)
06-27 11:03:42.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14489): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If anybody wants to try it out for themselves, I am using the example provided [here in the SMSDemo project](http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/).

Can anybody help me out with this?

**EDIT :**
I have just put together a sample J2ME MIDlet to see if I can get it to work as well and it also fails.  Does anybody remember any information about port-directed SMS?  Is it handled differently on different networks? Is it all just outdated and I need to get with the times?  Or is it something that I might be doing?

In case SMS is network dependent, I'm using Sprint devices but I'm developing in Canada, so I think they are roaming on Telus.